# angualrjs route loading different background on each page. but body default color creating a white splash

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using angularjs route to deliver different pages.
I have my body background set to white. I am dynamically loading different background on each of my pages on top of it in a wrapper div. Now the problem is between the pages the body color shows up and gives a white splash. It looks really bad at user view. Is there any way to make this white background not load. I tried making body transparent but that did not work. tried to change color of body to black or some other color, still did not look good.

Splash screen is the solution of my problem..is it not?

Comment: why you can't set body background color instead of wrapper div's in each route?

Comment: I tried that, the default color still creates same problem. because first that loads, then changes to new background.

Comment: I think i will need a splash screen.